# Is the inverse square law affected by the surface size of the Lightsource?

Tags: optics, visible-light, luminosity

Lets say I have 2 fully illuminated lighsources.

Lightsource A and B.

B has 10 times larger illumining surface than A.

Both have the same distance from the point of mesurement (in lux).

By the "inverse square law" of light, the messured intensity increases to the square of the distance?

I have messured 1lx at a distance of 200m of both lightsources.

So if I want to know how much Luminosity both lightsources have at the distance of 100m I use the Inverse Square Law:

$$
1lx * (\frac{200m}{100m})^2 = 1lx * 2^2 = 1lx * 4 = 4lx
$$

Now the mystery to me is, how important is the size of the lightsource?
I can't wrap my head arround it, because with this law "size does not matter" because both would have 4lx at 100m distance.

How would the luminosity differ?

Example image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The inverse law is irrelevant here. If B is 10 times larger than A, its luminosity at each distance will be 10 times larger than that of A, regardless of how the luminosity of A changes with distance. This is because light adds linearly, that is, if you double the amount of light then you double its luminosity.

Note: you need to be careful with what do you mean by B being 10 larger than A, do you mean that the surface is 10 times larger, or the linear dimensions larger? you would have a different answer on each case. If you have 10 times the linear size, the surface will increase 100 times, and so the total luminosity.

Comment: I assume he means that the brightness is the same aka the same energy being released per second. however one is spread over a large volume

Comment: Yes but I messured both lights at a distance of 200m. Both have 1lux at 200m.
Not the general measurement. Just how applies the law, if I already have meassured 1lx at 200m. Do I have to account for object size, when calculating the closer distance ? How would the formular look like?

Answer (score 0):

By the application of gauss law for a general inverse square law.

Given that L= kr^/r^2

then via gauss law  the Surface integral L .da =4pi*(K enclosed)
now for a point source the field is just kr^2/r^2

However if K follows a density distribution such that K = triple Integral p dv then. k enclosed for a spherical distribution of radius R would be p*(4/3*pi*R^3) so using gauss law

4pi* K enclosed = 4*pi* p*(4/3)*pi*R^3

using arguments from spherical symmetry we get that surface integral L =L*(4Pi*r^2) where r is the radius of my gaussian surface

equating the two expressions:

L*(4pi*r^2)=4*pi*p*(4/3)*pi*R^3

L*r^2=p*(4/3)*pi*R^3

L=(p*(4/3)*pi*R^3)/r^2

Well this certainly doesn't look to be the same field as a point K field. however realising that p by definition is K/(4/3*pi*R^3)

we get back that L =k/r^2

which is the same for a Point K field.

(FYI by simply using gauss law alone and taking it as true we can actually just say that the field of a K distribution  will have the same K enclosed by a gaussian surface  where the surface radius is larger then then distribution radius to simply say the field.isnthe same l. however I wanted to show you the density way as it can be generalised to inside the object.

To summarise, Learn gauss law and then it is obvious. the size of an object has no effect on intensity given that the two stars actually have the same brightness but one is spread out over a larger volume. THIS IS NOT TRUE FOR INSIDE THE STAR THOUGH, Obviously larger starts produce MORE energy avg so this analysis isn't true however a more.suitable generalisation is replacing luminosity  with charge, or mass

Comment: So the calculation in my Question are correct? And If I measured in both cases I measure 1lux at 200m, the calculation at 100m will be 4lux. But the surface of the luminous object will be dimmer the larger it is?

Comment: The calculation in your questions are correct. as a 1/r^2 field of a spherical distribution acts as though the object were a point source. I dont like this question as it confuses people as to what the light sources represent. I'm going to change the question  about mass   and the objects having the same mass. the surface on the smaller object will have a higher field than the surface of a larger object  as it  has a smaller radius as per 1/r^2

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. given that the total brightness of the object is the same for both cases but one is spread out over a larger volume,then radius doesn't matter. however if one is 10x larger in thst the brightness IS 10X LARGER then your answer will be 10x.

Comment: Sorry. Its really abstract. I uptated the question to surface size. Additionally. For me its not important how bright the lightsource is in total. I just want to know if I have to calculate the size, when I want to have the Luminositiy at a poit X if I know one Masurement at the Distance at 200m.